# Vue.js CLI 3, Express.js, Bootstrap Error rendering the app

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, bootstrap-4

the app is running perfectly fine in the development mode, However, I am facing an issue when using the build mode. with an Express server.js file, the app doesn't even gets rendered by testing my server.js file locally.

below are two similar versions of my server.js file, none of them is working and both are logging the same error which i also attached a screenshot to it below

```js
// version one
const express = require('express');

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

let app = express();



app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/dist/"));

app.get(/.*/, (req, res) => {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/dist/index.html'); //path to index.html
  });

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Listening on port ' + port)
});
```

```js
//version two
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const serveStatic = require('serve-static');

let app = express();
app.use(serveStatic(__dirname + "/dist"));


const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;


app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join( __dirname, './dist/index.html')); //path to index.html
  });

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Listening on port ' + port)
});
```

below are the errors i a getting in the console[image]

[image]

the app.vue file

[image]
main.js

Comment: Could you show your root .vue file (e. g. `App.vue`)?

Comment: done, i added a screenshot to both my app.vue and my main.js

Comment: tell me if you need to check something more, and thanks anyway

Comment: One possible error could be a missing `export default { ... }` in one of the `.vue` files. Check them all.

Comment: unfortunately not, i have the `export default { .. }` block in all my `.vue` files. tho, I tried something interesting, in my server.js file,  i did the following when requesting the root of the app : `app.get('/', (req, res) => { res.send("this is the response")})` . this code should send me that text in the broswer, yet i got the same annoying error, i mean i think the issue is not with the express now, this maybe has to do with the vue CLI integration with bootstrap.. I am not sure to be frank :S